# Pandas: Parse xml column and split into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have a dataframe that looks like this (1 sample row)

```
    Title   Date    Supervisor  Nightshift  XML
    NaN 27/10/2021  Michael Myres   No    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Repeate...
```

The dataframe has one column that an contains nested XML (below)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RepeaterData>
    <Version />
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <TestReference type="System.String">**1203**</TestReference>
            <Discipline type="System.String">**Bodyshop**</Discipline>
            <WON type="System.String">**1234**</WON>
            <PurchaseOrder type="System.String">**1234**</PurchaseOrder>
            <LabourType type="System.String">**On Tools**</LabourType>
            <WorkType type="System.String">**Turnaround**</WorkType>
            <TestEngineer type="System.String">**Me**</TestEngineer>
            <_x0034_4508821-eb2d-45be-b408-5db4df886890 type="System.String">&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;utf-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;RepeaterData&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Version /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Items&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_EmployeeName type=&amp;quot;System.String&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**Elliot**&amp;lt;/control_EmployeeName&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_NHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**1**&amp;lt;/control_NHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_PHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**2**&amp;lt;/control_PHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_DHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**3**&amp;lt;/control_DHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_EmployeeName type=&amp;quot;System.String&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**Ryan** &amp;lt;/control_EmployeeName&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_NHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**1**&amp;lt;/control_NHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_PHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**2**&amp;lt;/control_PHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_DHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**4**&amp;lt;/control_DHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_EmployeeName type=&amp;quot;System.String&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**Elliot**&amp;lt;/control_EmployeeName&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_NHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**1**&amp;lt;/control_NHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_PHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**1**&amp;lt;/control_PHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;control_DHours type=&amp;quot;System.Int32&amp;quot;&amp;gt;1&amp;lt;/control_DHours&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Items&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/RepeaterData&amp;gt;</_x0034_4508821-eb2d-45be-b408-5db4df886890>
            <f91faab4-2d9d-4c1f-a40c-63c6a3d71572 type="System.String">&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;utf-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;RepeaterData&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Version /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Items&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;NonProductiveTime type=&amp;quot;System.String&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Additional duties&amp;lt;/NonProductiveTime&amp;gt;&amp;lt;NonProductiveTimeMinutes type=&amp;quot;System.Double&amp;quot;&amp;gt;**15**&amp;lt;/NonProductiveTimeMinutes&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Item&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Items&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/RepeaterData&amp;gt;</f91faab4-2d9d-4c1f-a40c-63c6a3d71572>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</RepeaterData>
```

I would like to parse the XML column and split the xml ** values ** into separate rows

Expected result

```
       Date      Supervisor Nightshift  TestReference Discipline   WON  PurchaseOrder LabourType    WorkType TestEngineer EmployeeName  Nhours  Phours  Dhours
0 2021-10-27  Michael Myres         No           1203   Bodyshop  1234           1234   On Tools  Turnaround           Me       Elliot       1       2       3
1 2021-10-27  Michael Myres         No           1203   Bodyshop  1234           1234   On Tools  Turnaround           Me         Ryan       1       2       4
2 2021-10-27  Michael Myres         No           1203   Bodyshop  1234           1234   On Tools  Turnaround           Me         John       1       1       1
```

I have tried solution below but it just yields

```
    Version Items   Version Items   Version Items   Version Items   Version Items   Version Items
    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

---

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

df = pd.read_csv('SharePointDataPull.csv')

xml_data = df['XML'][0] # test row 
root = ET.XML(xml_data)  # Parse XML

for i, child in enumerate(root):
    data.append([subchild.text for subchild in child])
    cols.append(child.tag)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T  # Write in DF and transpose it
df1.columns = cols  # Update column names
df1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html look like it does what you want?

Comment: It also looks like the XML data you want to work with is *twice* HTML encoded; that is, `&amp;lt;` decodes once to `&lt;` which decodes to `<` -- so you need to `html.unescape(html.unescape( [stuff here] ))`

Comment: Would you confirm, in your expected result, what you expect the 'Date' column to be populated with? In your initial dataframe, you have a single 'Date' of `27/10/2021` -- how does this expand to the 27th thru the 29th in your expected output?

Comment: Hi Joshua thanks for your help, really appreciate it. My mistake,  Date column should all have the date 27/10/2021

Comment: In your example, what happens to your `f91faab4-2d9d-4c1f-a40c-63c6a3d71572` tag and its contents? (Which contain `NonProductiveTime` and `NonProductiveTimeMinutes` tags, but not in matching amounts to the "rows" in the `_x0034_4508821-eb2d-45be-b408-5db4df886890` tag.)

Comment: The values under f91faab4-2d9d-4c1f-a40c-63c6a3d71572 will be separated out into a different dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Would you confirm that you're effectively trying to construct the following DataFrame from the 0-indexed 7th tag in each row's XML string?

```
  EmployeeName  Nhours  Phours  Dhours
0       Elliot       1       2       3
1         Ryan       1       2       4
2         John       1       1       1
```

And that the list of columns you're looking for the "main" dataframe to contain is as below (`SUBFRAME` subject to your naming preference)? Or is that list of columns variable for each row?

```
['Date', 'Supervisor', 'Nightshift', 'TestReference', 'Discipline', 'WON', 'PurchaseOrder', 'LabourType', 'WorkType', 'TestEngineer', 'SUBFRAME']
```

Snippet below tracking what I have so far:

```py
import html

# change from string of XML data to XML-parsed object
df.XML = df.XML.apply(ET.XML).apply(lambda root: root[1][0])
```

Comment: Yes Nearly there!, The  required columns  for df1 required are ['Date', 'Supervisor', 'Nightshift', 'TestReference', 'Discipline', 'WON', 'PurchaseOrder', 'LabourType', 'WorkType', 'TestEngineer',  'EmployeeName', 'NHours', 'PHours', 'DHours',]

Comment: Hi Josh did you make anymore progress on this?